# Run wget to download several files in shell script

Tags: shell, wget

I'm trying to download some file by wget.  But it seems that the number "i" is unworkable.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i == 1; i <= 10; i++))
do
    wget -r ftp://example/hw/"$i"/test*
done
```

It showed the link "ftp://example/hw//test*" on the cmd.
The number did not be printed out.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    wget -r ftp://example/hw/"$i"/test*
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your `for` loop should be a bit different:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 10; i++))
```

(have one `=` instead of two)
And also is good practice to use variables on this way:

```
wget -r ftp://example/hw/"${i}"/test*
```

Comment: I don't see much advantage in using curly braces here, I would definitely quote `test*`, As it is written now, the shell would try to expand the glob, most likely fail to do so, print an error message because of this, and pass the glob unchanged to `wget`, and because of this, the _wget_ would work. But if the code is one day embedded in a bash, which has _nullglob_  turned on, the ftp-argument to _wget_ would be silently deleted, leaving you  with a lone `wget -r`.  You can try it with a `shopt -s nullglob;  echo wget -r ftp://example/hw/"${i}"/test*`.